# (Discord.py) Pin a message

Tags: python, discord

I have a self bot for discord, I have used [MusicBot](https://github.com/Just-Some-Bots/MusicBot) as a base for the project, they're unable to give support on modifying the bot, I'm not a very confident python programmer. 
 What I'd like it to do is for a user to use `{command_prefix}pin [Message ID]` and be able to pin the message.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pin_message(message)` to pin the message.

You can use `get_message(channel, id)` or `logs_from(channel, Amount)` to get the message, though `Get_message()` is more direct but requires message ID, but `logs_from()` does not require ID but requires some more small steps to get the message you want.